# Ceiling fan noise is it normal or abnormal?

Tags: ceiling-fan, bedroom

I recently installed a new ceiling fan in my bedroom . A Case Endeavor fan.

It wobbles a little bit, really a 'little' (maybe it is me)  so I've been attempting to balance it .

However the larger issue is: it makes a bit of a noise in the low speed, and I'm unsure if the noise is "normal" or a sign that something needs to be adjusted .

I do appreciate a completely silent room when I'm sleeping at night

There are videos that say noisy fans are probably cheap fans or maybe something is loose .

Is a ceiling fan supposed to be absolutely silent, or is it that there is some noise which is a swirling of air when a consistent basis as the fan rotates ? Or is ceiling fan silence too close to perfection that is impossible to achieve with any kind of mechanical device ?

Comment: I'm not clear: you're asking us to post a video discussing just how quiet ceiling fans should be?

Comment: Some fans 'hum' more than others - particularly on a low speed setting. If it bothers you then you could disassemble the fan and soak all of the motor windings in a epoxy or something to stop them vibrating and then hopefully reassemble it - or you could just return it and buy a better made (probably more expensive) fan...

Comment: Without hearing it, it's impossible to say if it's normal.  Post a video somewhere, and link to it in your question.

Comment: Also how are you controlling the speeds? with a pull chain on the fan itself that produces fixed speeds?  a wall switch speed control with fixed speeds? or a wall switch control with variable speed?  Some external controls (especially variable speed controls, will produce motor hum at certain speeds.

Answer (score 1):

Ceiling fans are not generally silent. There is some motor hum, which may be transmitted to and reinforced by the ceiling, and there is some "white noise" as the blades cut through and move the air.

Yes, some are quieter than others, by design or by the luck of installation. Whether yours is typical or not is best answered by your visiting a few friends who have these and comparing theirs to yours. It's also possible that someone like Consumer Reports has rated models/manufacturers on this; do some websearching.

Remember that in many cases the alternative is an air conditioner, which would be much louder. And most folks adjust to most noises, and learn to stop hearing the unimportant ones. I doubt your bedroom is really as quiet as you think it is.